# MailyHerald setup with Devise gem (error: NoMethodError at /user)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, sidekiq, mailing

I’m trying to setup MailyHerald with devise gem in a rails 4 app.
I followed these steps:
https://github.com/Sology/maily_herald/wiki/Setup-with-'devise'-gem

Now, when I try to register a new user (a confirmation mail should be sent via MailyHerald) I get this error:

```
NoMethodError at /user
undefined method `[]' for false:FalseClass

maily_herald (0.9.3) lib/maily_herald.rb

# Gets the Maily logger.
def logger
  unless MailyHerald::Logging.initialized?
    opts = {
      level: options[:verbose] ? Logger::DEBUG : Logger::INFO,
    }
    opts[:target] = options[:logfile] if options[:logfile]
    MailyHerald::Logging.initialize(opts)
  end
```

Any idea? Thanks

**EDIT**:
A small update, maybe related to the error I get:

when I do

```
maily_herald paperboy --start
```

as indicated in the page [above](https://github.com/Sology/maily_herald/wiki/Setup-with-'devise'-gem), I get

```
undefined method `merge' for false:FalseClass
```

**EDIT 2:**
Ok, I did some test.

I created a new app with devise from scratch (rails 4.2.5.1 and ruby 2.2.4p230).
Now I get no error when a user registers, but no confirmation email is sent.

Running background processing

```
maily_herald paperboy --start
```

returns this

```
[Maily#cli] INFO: Started with options: {:mode=>:paperboy, :action=>:start, :daemon=>true}
You really should set a logfile if you're going to daemonize
/Users/fabbrro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@testMailyHerald/gems/maily_herald-0.9.3/lib/maily_herald/cli.rb:200:in `daemonize'
/Users/fabbrro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@testMailyHerald/gems/maily_herald-0.9.3/lib/maily_herald/cli.rb:45:in `paperboy'
/Users/fabbrro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@testMailyHerald/gems/maily_herald-0.9.3/bin/maily_herald:10:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/fabbrro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@testMailyHerald/bin/maily_herald:23:in `load'
/Users/fabbrro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@testMailyHerald/bin/maily_herald:23:in `<main>'
/Users/fabbrro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@testMailyHerald/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/fabbrro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@testMailyHerald/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>’
```

To further investigate, I'm also trying to setup the [sample application](https://github.com/Sology/maily_testapp). I created some entity (users) and tried to send them emails (via mailcatcher).
Until now, even if devise gem is not installed, It seems I have no luck:
no message at all when running background processing,
no errors,
but also no mail is sent. Did someone managed to successfully try the app ?

Comment: Did you restart your server after the set up?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, SsouLlesS. I restarted the server, but the error persists and no email is sent.

Comment: I tried to set up maily_herald with devise following the guide, and I also have the same issue, it seems to be a bug of maily_herald, I already oponed up an issue in github let's see if the maintainers take a look

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it. I'll also follow the opened issue on github

Comment: @fabbrro - I had the same log message pop up into my version of maily_herald.  So I decided to fork the gem and see what was going on underneath the hood.

As it turns out, for some reason, the logfile I was specifying in my maily_herald.yml file was not being parsed in properly by the gem.

What I did to fix it was fork the file.  In the cli.rb file, the daemonize method was pulling in options["logfile"] instead of options[:logfile] .. so I just added this line:

`options[:logfile] = options["logfile"]`

Not elegant but it works ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just noticed this question. Have You looked at my comment on github?

https://github.com/Sology/maily_herald/issues/17#issuecomment-182412069

Also, I checked my `Procfile` and I'm running:

```
web: bundle exec rails s
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -v
paperboy: bundle exec maily_herald paperboy
```

`Sidekiq` is essential for `MailyHerald`. I think it's not specified on Wiki page. let me know if this solves Your problem. I'll try also setup fresh app with Your setup. Any public repo I can look into?

**UPDATE**

Just created fresh app:

- https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-devise
- https://github.com/Sology/maily_herald/wiki/Setup-with-'devise'-gem
- `gem install mailcatcher`
- `mailcatcher`
- `gem install foreman`
- create `Procfile` in your app directory, with this code:

  ```
  web: bundle exec rails s
  worker: bundle exec sidekiq -v
  paperboy: bundle exec maily_herald paperboy
  ```
- `foreman start`

Then open mailcatcher and app in browser and sign up new user. You should see newly added mailing into dispatcher and sidekiq logs running this.

Comment: Thanks to your help I finally found out what was the problem:
following the github page, I created the file maily_herald.yml trying to configure maily_herald and I had left it empty. Once removed, I was able to solve the problem. 
Anyway, I accept your answer. It's thanks to the sample app you posted that I understand how to correctly setup and run mail_herald and I could compare the two apps to find the problem.
It's true, how to setup Sidekiq via Procfile is not well specified on wiki page. I was not running it in the right way.
Maily_herald seems to work correctly in my app now. Thanks!